# MongoDB count if exists and grouped by distinct array values

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a collection looking like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "category" : [
         {
           "name": "category1"
         },
         {
           "name": "category2"
         }
    ],
    "event": [
               {
                 type: "house"
               },
               {
                 type: "mouse"
               }
             ]
},

{
    "_id" : 2,
    "category" : [
         {
           "name": "category2"
         },
         {
           "name": "category3"
         }
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : 3,
    "category" : [
         {
           "name": "category3"
         },
         {
           "name": "category1"
         }
    ],
        "event": [
           {
             type: "mouse"
           }
         ]
}
```

I need to do a group by distinct category name types and count if an event exists to get a document like:

```
{ "category1": total_count: 2,
  "category2": total_count: 0,
  "category3": total_count: 1}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should use the aggregation pipeline. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, but without success.. it would work if category isn't an array, but i don't know how to "explode" the array first and then group it by distinct values of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it works for me:

```
db.getCollection('coll').aggregate([
{$unwind: "$category"},
{$group :{
    _id : "$category.name",   
    total_count : {$sum : 1}
 }
}])
```

Comment: unwind! that's it

Comment: @Codutie yep :)